# error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: java, c, windows, cygwin

I'm trying to diagnose (and fix) a problem that sits on the boundary of several components; any insights into how to either gain more information or outright resolve the issue is very much appreciated.

I have an application which starts as a C program that may launch a Java program and may then launch the same C program in a recursive fashion. **It has been working on both Linux and Cygwin.** Some bugs were found in the program launching paradigm within Java, and it was updated from the simpler Runtime strategy to the (new in 1.5) ProcessBuilder strategy. For various unsundry reasons, **it launches bash with the -c option followed by whatever** it is that needs to be called.  It works on Linux, but when ported to Cygwin, it fails as described below. Unfortunately, I accidentally deleted the working Cygwin instance, so I can't readily discern if the issue is merely a configuration issue or something deeper.

For the record, I don't think there's anything wrong with Cygwin, but I'm not sure because I had foolishly updated Cygwin at the same time. (What *was* I thinking?!)

The error comes when Java is trying to launch the C program. It's always exactly the same error:

> **error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object
>   file: No such file or directory**

Research on this error within cygwin yields nearly nothing, only this:
http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2012-03/msg00396.html

Notably, tests running images that are a part of the standard Cygwin distribution run and work fine. In contrast, the program bs.exe is compiled and linked in the Cygwin environment.

Some things I was considering was if perhaps there are environment variables I've not included in the environment, but it's supposed to inherit the caller's environ, and I don't see that I've ever used any kind of LD_LIBRARY_PATH in cygwin environments in the past and didn't notice any similar references in the literature. Then, there's the Java policies, but that hasn't changed any from before, and when I added cygwin to the file, it didnt' help.

...I've run out of ideas... Anybody?

UPDATE: Here's a code excerpt of the ProcessBuilder code in Java:

```
public results ExecuteProgram(String program, String log)
{
   results r = new results();
   boolean returnString = false;
   if (Empty(log)) { log = getTempFile(); }
   File lf = null;
   ProcessBuilder pb;
   r.OK = true;
   r.err = "Unable to Run program: ";
   int status = 0; //Note that 0 = success!
   // Before we get here, we know the first space delimited substring
   // of the program string already has the full path to the program. The
   // rest (if any) are arguments.

   try
   { 
      // Shell contains something like /bin/bash, depending on the system
      //
      pb = new ProcessBuilder(Shell, "-c", program);

      // Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
      // env.remove("PATH");
      // env.put("PATH", Path);
      // env.remove("CLASSPATH");
      // env.put("CLASSPATH", CLASSPATH);
      // env.remove("LD_LIBRARY_PATH");
      // env.put("LD_LIBRARY_PATH", LD_LIBRARY_PATH);
      // ALSO DO:
      // LD_LIBRARY_PATH

      pb.directory(new File(wd));
      pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
      lf = new File(log); 
      pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.appendTo(lf)); 
      Process p = pb.start();
      assert p.getInputStream().read() == -1;
      if (!returnString)
      {
         assert pb.redirectInput() == Redirect.PIPE;
         assert pb.redirectOutput().file() == lf;
      }
      r.err = "OS Process started."; 
      r.OK = true; 
      try 
      {   
         r.Status = p.exitValue(); 
         r.err = "OS Process completed."; 
      }   
      catch (IllegalThreadStateException e)   
      {   
      }   
   }
   catch (IOException e)
   {
      r.err += "\nIOException while accessing IO stream: "+
       e.toString();
      r.OK = false;
   }
   if ((r.Status == 0) && (r.OK))
   {
      r.err = "Success";
   } else {
      if (r.Status != 0)
      {
         r.err += "Process exit status: "+r.Status;
      }
      System.out.print(r.err);
   }
   return r;
}
```

Oh yes, and as per the usual, cygcheck -s information follows, snipped a little. More on request as the whole dataset is huge and probably uninteresting.

> Cygwin Configuration Diagnostics  Current System Time: Thu Dec 05
>   04:08:40 2013    Windows 7 Professional N Ver 6.1 Build 7600
>   Running under WOW64 on AMD64   Path:   C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin
>           C:\opt\bin
>           C:\cygwin\usr\local\bin 
>           C:\cygwin\bin 
>           C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools
>           C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin
>           C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin
>           C:\Program Files (x87)\PC Connectivity Solution
>           C:\windows\system32
>           C:\windows
>           C:\windows\System32\Wbem
>           C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
>           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn
>           C:\Program Files (x86)\Toshiba\Bluetooth Toshiba Stack\sys
>           C:\Program Files (x86)\Toshiba\Bluetooth Toshiba Stack\sys\x64
>           C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin 
>           C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon
>           C:\cygwin\bin 
>           C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin
>           C:\cygwin\lib\lapack
>
> ```
> Cygwin DLL version info: 
>     DLL version: 1.8.4 
>     DLL epoch: 19 
>     DLL old termios: 5 
>     DLL malloc env: 28
>     Cygwin conv: 181 
>     API major: 0 
>     API minor: 262 
>     Shared data: 5 
>     DLL identifier: cygwin1 
>     Mount registry: 3 
>     Cygwin registry name: Cygwin 
>     Program options name: Program Options
>     Installations name: Installations  
>     Cygdrive default prefix:
>     Build date:
>     Shared id: cygwin1S5
>       <snip>
> ```

Comment: How exactly are you launching bash from java? You mention ProcessBuilder but I'd like see the code... maybe try "/usr/bin/env bash -c".

Comment: @ElliotFrisch ...OK, code excerpt added...

Comment: @ElliotFrisch ...BTW, the env call - you want the environment variables output? OK, I can do that... But why call bash afterwards? As an aside, your example wouldn't work because the code would take "bash" and "-c" as arguments to env - presuming there was a program env at /usr/bin.

Comment: Actually Richard, bash isn't always in /bin (or /usr/bin) - using (/usr/bin/env bash) is going to search the environment for bash.

Comment: @ElliotFrisch Yes, well aware that bash can be somewhere else, that's why its provided via the variable "shell" - which, incidentally, gets checked during an initialization phase. ...doesn't one usually use 'which' to find an image? (BTW, sorry for the delay - flu.)

Comment: Any solution? I'm stuck on a similar error