# Calling Cygwin from python fails with: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, windows, cygwin

I have a C program compiled with GCC using Cygwin, which I want to run from a python program in windows 7. I got as far as using the subprocess module, but was getting the "error while loading shared libraries..." and no other information.

Googling resulted in the following two questions; one with no answer and one with an accepted answer that didn't (on first reading) fully explain how to fix it, and a comment promising a full solution from almost two years ago.

[error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20392789/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-)

[Launching CYGWIN-built executable from Java on Windows 7 fails with "error while loading shared libraries: ?: No such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092730/launching-cygwin-built-executable-from-java-on-windows-7-fails-with-error-whilesuch)

I've in fact fixed my issue, but I wanted to document it here in case anyone else has the same issue.

Comment: Is the cygwin.dll in your path (or in the current directory) ?

Comment: Actually, that is a point. I assumed that was not the problem, as comments in the questions I linked to state that moving the dll didn't help. But I didn't check.

Comment: I'm confused. You admit the path was the issue -- but your comment suggests this was some sort of test for the SO community?

Comment: What? No, just that I couldn't find a clear answer despite spending all afternoon looking, and I wanted to save anyone else the frustration. My question specifically says I fixed my issue, but I wanted to document it. Copying cygwin.dll might very well also have worked, but the only answer I could find said "copy the cygwin dependent dlls" without saying what they were, and other comments in the question said that hadn't worked anyway, so I didn't try it.

Comment: You wanted someone to tell you where on your system cygwin was installed? I'm curious -- if you fixed the problem mentioned by another post, why didn't you just add your suggested fix there, rather than open a new SO question?

Comment: Maybe I should have, but I haven't in fact fixed the problem in the other posts. I've fixed a similar problem, that I encountered separately, which I assume is the same thing but may not be. To be thorough, I should really check whether copying the dll also works - but if it does work, that implies this is a separate issue, since it didn't work for the other posts.

Comment: You might want to review http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#search_order_for_desktop_applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10092994/1856824) to the second question is correct (at least in my case) - it's all to do with where the working directory is, and whether it contains the cygwin dlls.

I was calling `C:\\cygwin\\bin\\bash.exe` from the working directory of my python program, meaning bash.exe was looking for whatever libraries it needed in the python working directory, the libraries being located in C:\cygwin\bin.

Since I'm using Popen in python, if I include the argument `cwd="C:\\cygwin\\bin\\"` in the Popen call, it starts bash.exe with the current working directory set to cygwin\bin, and everything works fine.

**EDIT:**
Alternatively, copying the relevant dlls to the working directory of the python program will have the same effect. However, copying just cygwin1.dll doesn't work (at least for me), and there are a lot of other cygwin dlls. If you can work out which ones you need and just copy them (or copy all of them) then that also works.